# How to use a separate profile/environment data source for Micronaut test in Kotlin?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, testing, kotlin, micronaut

I'm trying to use **two data sources** for my Micronaut web application written in Kotlin: **the one with a mysql database, and one in memory H2 database to be used when executing the tests**.

I've tried using only the `h2` database as the default production data source, so the configuration fields regarding it should be correct.

The application runs as expected with the mysql data source by executing `./gradlew run`

1. I've tried placing the data sources in separate configuration files, `application.yml` and `application-test.yml` in `src/main/resources/` directory and also placing only `application-test.yml` in `src/test/resources/`, without result.
2. Adding `@MicronautTest` annotation declaring there the `test` environment and `application = BookieSparaerverApplication` params didn't work.
3. Adding `@TypeHint(Genre::class, Book::class, DefaultGenreRepository::class)` annotation to `BookieServerApplication` didn't work.

These are the relevant fields of the `src/main/resources/application.yml` configuration file

```
datasources:
  default:
    url: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookie-server?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false'
    dbCreate: create-update
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    username: root
    password: root

jpa:
  default:
    entity-scan:
      packages:
        - 'com.transgressoft.bookieserver.domain'
    properties:
      hibernate:
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: update
        show_sql: true
```

And this is the `src/test/resources/application-test.yml` file:

```
datasources:
  default:
    url: ${JDBC_URL:`jdbc:h2:mem:default;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE`}
    username: ${JDBC_USER:sa}
    password: ${JDBC_PASSWORD:""}
    driverClassName: ${JDBC_DRIVER:org.h2.Driver}

jpa:
  default:
    entity-scan:
      packages:
        - 'com.transgressoft.bookieserver.domain'
    properties:
      hibernate:
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: update
        show_sql: true
```

When I execute the test (`GenreControllerSpec` in the code), looks like the `EntityManager` bean is not created and therefore the DAO class cannot be instantiated (in my code is the `GenreRepository` class).

This is the full log message:

```
Internal Server Error: Failed to inject value for parameter [entityManager] of class: com.transgressoft.bookieserver.domain.$DefaultGenreRepositoryDefinition$Intercepted

Message: No bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
Path Taken: new $GenreControllerDefinition$Intercepted([GenreRepository genreRepository],BeanContext beanContext,Interceptor[] interceptors) --> new $DefaultGenreRepositoryDefinition$Intercepted([EntityManager entityManager],ConfigurationProperties applicationConfiguration,BeanContext beanContext,Interceptor[] interceptors)
io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException: Internal Server Error: Failed to inject value for parameter [entityManager] of class: com.transgressoft.bookieserver.domain.$DefaultGenreRepositoryDefinition$Intercepted
```

The full project code is accesible here
https://github.com/octaviospain/bookie-server/tree/feature/jpa-and-hibernate and to reproduce above logs just execute `./gradlew test` and open the report, or run it with logs activated.

EDIT: I've updated the description with Ivan Lopez's suggestion, but error and expected result remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example application is using 1.1.1 of `micronaut-hibernate-jpa` which does not support

```
jpa:
  default:
    entity-scan:
      packages:
        - 'com.transgressoft.bookieserver.domain'
```

You must use `jpa.default.packages-to-scan` instead as the [documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-sql/1.1.1/guide/#hibernate) states.

Comment: Thanks, that made work the EntityManager to be created and used in the tests, but only this thing is missing to make the test use the test profile and therefore the h2 datasource `ApplicationContext.run(EmbeddedServer::class.java, "test")`

Answer (score 4):

I think you have missunderstood how defining datasources work.
When setting:

```
datasources:
  production:
    ...

  test:
    ...

jpa:
  production:
    ...

  test:
    ...
```

You are telling Micronaut: "I want you to create *two* datasources, one named `production` and other named `test` *at the same time*. Both datasources will be available to the application and you can inject them using the names defined (`production` and `test`) and qualifiers.

What you need to do is define in `src/main/resources/application.yml` only one datasource. Micronaut use `default` name as the default one:

```
datasources:
  default:
    ... // your production MySQL database 

jpa:
  default:
    ... // configuration for MySQL database
```

And then you can override anything defined in `application.yml` just creating `src/test/resources/application-test.yml` with the content:

```
datasources:
  default:
    ... // your test H2 database 

jpa:
  default:
    ... // configuration for H2 database
```

Hope it makes sense. You can find more information about it here: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#config

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but the result and logs are the same, and it doesn't solve what I'm trying to achieve. In fact I've edited the question with your suggestion in the config so other users can focus on solving it too.
Please take a minute on the code provided (now updated) and check that it has the same result as described.

Comment: Hi, I ended up on this thread looking for the same answer, following your suggestion almost works but my repository does not work unless I hardcode the dialect inside the annotation like `@JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.H2)` shouldn't the dialect be coming from the properties file? I get `table not found error` unless dialect is specified!

Comment: @Sap If you use Micronaut Data JDBC then yes, you need to define the dialect in the annotation and in the configuration. See https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/index.html#_setting_the_dialect
The reason is that queries are pre-computed at compile time so they need to be prepared for the right database and can't be "generic"

Comment: So moving to JPA should solve this problem? If yes then I will spend time fixing `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement` which I get after migrating to JPA+Hiberante

Comment: I also get Table "" not found; SQL statement: before this message

Comment: @Sap I am having the same problem, app will be using mysql and for integration tests, I want to use h2. But as @JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.H2) this is mandatory on repository, I can't use micronaut-data-jdbc then?

Comment: @amitb10 I just ended up using test containers and kept an application.yml in test/resources folder